# Failed to construct kafka producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

I'm using Kafka version 0.11.0.0 and trying to create an input stream by loading data from avro file.But it fails in instantiating the Producer with the exception:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer - Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:415)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:287)
    at wordcount.PayloadProducer.produceInputs(PayloadProducer.java:42)
    at wordcount.PayloadProducer.main(PayloadProducer.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.<init>(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:47)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerDe.configureClientProperties(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDe.java:73)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.configure(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:42)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.configure(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.configure(ExtendedSerializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:336)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

I'm following this link for my work: [Confluent kafka stream example](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/3.3.0-post/kafka-streams/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/TopArticlesLambdaExample.java)

Code for instantiating Producer:

```
 final Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
            props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
            props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                    io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
            props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);

            GenericRecordBuilder pageViewBuilder = new GenericRecordBuilder(loadSchema("payload.avsc"));

            KafkaProducer<String, GenericRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by exception, you miss `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException` class

Did you clone the repository, or did you just copy paste the code? You need a correct `.pom`, like this one:
https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/3.3.0-post/kafka-streams/pom.xml
Which include all correct dependancies, including jackson.

I would advise cloning the repository (at least everything from here: https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/3.3.0-post/kafka-streams) and follow commands and requirements stated in README to begin with.

Comment: I cloned the repo and then this exception.